# Exploring sadhanas for transformation: Overcoming the impact of birth on nature

Tags: scripture, caste-system, varna, sadhana, birth

In a fascinating discourse between Yudhishthira and Bhishma found in the Anusasanika Parva of the Mahabharata, Bhishma discusses the interplay between a person's birth and their conduct. He underscores the influence of birth on a person's disposition, but also highlights the transformative power of righteous conduct.

> A person that is born of an irregular union presents diverse features
> of disposition. One's purity of birth, again, is to be ascertained
> from one's acts which must resemble the acts of those who are
> admittedly good and righteous. A disrespectable behaviour, acts
> opposed to those laid down in the scriptures, crookedness and cruelty,
> and abstention from sacrifices and other spiritual acts that lead to
> merit, proclaim one's impurity of origin. A son receives the
> disposition of either the sire or the mother. Sometimes he catches the
> dispositions of both. A person of impure birth can never succeed in
> concealing his true disposition. As the cub of a tiger or a leopard
> resembles its sire and dam in form and in (the matter of) its stripes
> of spots, even so a person cannot but betray the circumstance of his
> origin. However covered may the course of one's descent be, if that
> descent happens to be impure, its character or disposition is sure to
> manifest itself slightly or largely. A person may, for purposes of his
> own, choose to tread on an insincere path, displaying such conduct as
> seems to be righteous. His own disposition, however, in the matter of
> those acts that he does, always proclaims whether he belongs to a good
> order or to a different one. Creatures in the world are endued with
> diverse kinds of disposition. They are, again, seen to be employed in
> diverse kinds of acts. Amongst creatures thus employed, there is
> nothing that is so good or precious as pure birth and righteous
> conduct. **If a person be born in a low order, that good understanding
> which arises from a study of the scriptures fails to rescue his body
> from low acts.** Absolute goodness of understanding may be of different
> degrees. It may be high, middling, or low. Even if it appears in a
> person of low extraction, it disappears like autumnal clouds without
> producing any consequences. On the other hand, that other goodness of
> understanding which, according to its measure, has ordained the status
> in which the person has been born, shows itself in his acts. If a
> person happens to belong to a superior order but still if he happens
> to be divested of good behaviour, he should receive no respect or
> worship. One may worship even a Sudra if he happens to be conversant
> with duties and be of good conduct. A person proclaims himself by his
> own good and acts and by his good or bad disposition and birth. **If
> one's race of birth happens to be degraded for any reason, one soon
> raises it and makes it resplendent and famous by one's acts.** For these
> reasons they that are endued with wisdom should avoid those women,
> among these diverse castes mixed or pure, upon whom they should not
> beget offspring.'
>
> [Section 49, Anusasanika Parva, The Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b014.htm)

In particular, Bhishma asserts that even with a deep understanding of the scriptures, a person born in a lower order may still be inclined towards "low acts". This poses a compelling question: do there exist spiritual practices or sadhanas that can help an individual overcome the tendencies instilled by their birth and transform their nature?

Indeed, in Sanatana Dharma, there are sadhanas recommended for every type of wish or desire, addressing an array of human concerns. Given this, it is plausible that there could be practices specifically aimed at altering the nature of one's body or disposition.

I am keen to explore this possibility further. Are there any scriptural references or teachings that outline such sadhanas? I am particularly interested in understanding the names and procedures of these sadhanas, and any scriptural passages that describe them in a context relevant to the discussion between Yudhishthira and Bhishma.

Comment: The Bhagavad Gita doesn’t seem to support change of body or disposition (svabhava/ prakriti). It may not be a sadhana but you’ll surely get an  answer in there.